# how to download an excel file from aspx webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, sql-server-2008

I am trying to fetch an excel file stored in bytes from database from an aspx webpage and download and open in .xls format, however the file is getting downloaded as .aspx . How to resolve this?

I tried:

```
    private void download(DataTable dt)
    {


        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["xyz"];
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
           // Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header. For example:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your-excel-file.xlsx
```

And in code:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=your-excel-file.xlsx");
```

Comment: Thank you. But it gives the file you are trying to open is in a different format  than specified by file extension . How to bypass that ?

Comment: Then the file you are sending to the client isn't an Excel file.

Comment: Actually I am saving the excel file in the database as varbinary(max) after converting it to bytes and then fetching it from there

Comment: Quite possibly, but something you are doing is messing up the content of it, and that's beyond the scope of this question. Open up the downloaded file in a text editor and see if you see anything unusual.